# Elasticsearch [Query Bool Must Match] performs OR operation instead of AND

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform a basic login operation where my view (front end part) accepts a username and password through a form

So in SQL, I must have an example query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $_POST['username'] AND password = $_POST['password'];
```

According to the official documentation of Elasticsearch PHP API, it must go like this:

```
$params = [
'index' => 'myIndex',
'type'  => 'myType',
'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            "bool" => [
                "must" => [
                    "match" => [ 
                        "username" => 'email@email.com',
                    ],
                    "match" => [
                        "password" => 'mypassword',
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Unfortunately, it is displaying **A LOT** of documents so I presumed it's performing the **OR** operator instead of matching them together

[image]

FYI, if you would ever wonder why would there be so many documents displayed according to the "hits" property above, there are literally many user documents with the same password

**Main Question** 
Is there any proper ES query to properly match my **username** `AND` **password** so I could only retrieve one document? I've been searching through with the official documentation, but nothing succeeds the desired output

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of sir Val, I was able to formulate a technique to try work-arounds for my query, and was able to display the result with the following:

```
$params = [
'index' => $index,
'type'  => 'index',
'size'  => 250,
'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [
                        "match" => [
                            "usr_username" => 
                                [
                                    "query" => $username,
                                    "operator" => "and"
                                ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        "match" => [
                            "usr_password" => [
                                "query" => $password,
                                "operator" => "and"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

[image]

Comment: I still would use a `term` query, because I think that your fields are of type `text`, not `keyword` (and are hence analyzed). If you don't, you might run into weird bug situations in the future.

Comment: sir @Val when I'm using the `term` query, there are no results shown :( and according to the documentation,(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#term-query-notes) they said to `Avoid using the term query for text fields`

Comment: Can you update your question with the mapping of your index?

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there. You need to enclose your `match` queries in one more array, otherwise your bool/must becomes an associative array and that's not what you want (i.e. the second match filter gets discarded).

```
$params = [
'index' => 'myIndex',
'type'  => 'myType',
'body'  => [
        'query' => [
            "bool" => [
                "must" => [
            -->   [
                    "match" => [ 
                        "username" => 'email@email.com',
                    ]
            -->   ],
            -->   [
                    "match" => [
                        "password" => 'mypassword',
                    ]
                  ]
            --> ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: hello and good day sir @Val thank you very much for the abrupt response! as for your answer, it still displays 9 documents but when I viewed it in the result, there are different emails still being fetched, any ideas about this one sir?

Comment: Try using a `term` query (input not analyzed) instead of a `match` query